# Add a function globally to use throughout an iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, function

I want to add a simple function to a central place so that I can use it without having to include the header files over and over again. How do I accomplish it?

Consider the function

```
void foo() {
    printf("Bar");
}
```

I tried adding this to a foo.h file and then including it in the prefix.pch file. But a compilation error occurs saying duplicate symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include your function in a separate class.
And include the header of that class to all of your classes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use inclusion guards, like this:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

void foo(); //declaration

#endif
```

And in `Foo.m`:

```
void foo() {
   printf("Bar");
}
```

Or, even easier, you can simply use the `#import` directive:

```
#import "Foo.h"
```

If you did all of the above, then the only way this could've happened is if you explicitly declared a new function with the same name inside another file

Comment: I did try both. But I get. _foo duplicate symbol used in Appdelegate.o and main.o

Comment: @Mahadevan S Did you by any chance import it into your App Delegate file as well? The only way this could've happened is if you explicitly declared a new function with the same name inside another file.

Comment: @Jacob: Its actually the function thats getting duplicated.

Comment: @Mahadevan S Also, run a project-wide search for `void foo()`

Comment: Yea.. I did that.. When I import the file in main.m, I can get the function to work. But at the place of calling, I'm getting a warning "Implicit declaration of function foo()"

Comment: Okay, that's fine. You'll need to declare the function, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

header (foo.h):

```
void foo();
```

implementation file (foo.m)

```
void foo() {
// blah
}
```

Stick your foo.h in your PCH and away you go.